# XA transaction in Apache Camel and Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: java, transactions, apache-camel

Rolling back the transaction does not work.

I tried to set the parameters in bean `ActiveMQComponent`:

- `cacheLevelName` => `CACHE_CONSUMER`
- `transacted` => `true`

How fix this error?

Log:

```
[ad #8 - JmsConsumer[Caosqueue]] TransactionErrorHandler        WARN  Transaction rollback (0x67756120) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID:stws2327-61437-1452674698638-1:3:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-stws2327-61436-1452674698403-0-3) due exchange was marked for rollbackOnly
[ad #8 - JmsConsumer[Caosqueue]] EndpointMessageListener        WARN  Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by:      [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.RollbackExchangeException: Intended rollback. Exchange[Message: two]]
```

Route:

```
<!-- Next route-->
<route autoStartup="true" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler" id="OperDayRoute">
  <from uri="jms:Caosqueue?transacted=true" />
  <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" />
  <setHeader headerName="body">
     <simple>${body}</simple>
  </setHeader>
  <to uri="sql:{{sql.insertBody}}"/>
  <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
  <choice>
    <when>
      <simple>${headers.CamelSqlUpdateCount} != 1</simple>
      <log message="PROCESSING RESULT IS ${body} - OK" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <log message="PROCESSING RESULT IS ${body} - NO OK!" />
      <camel:rollback markRollbackOnly="true" />
      <throwException ref="IllegalRez" />
    </otherwise>
  </choice>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem. Camel reports rollbacks in the logs under the `WARN` log level by default. You can change it to `DEBUG` if you wish.

In your Spring XML:

```
<bean id="transactionErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder">
    <property name="rollbackLoggingLevel" value="DEBUG"/>
    <property name="transactionTemplate" ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
</bean>

<!-- the standard spring transaction template for required -->
<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

It should be picked up automatically by Camel. If not, you can set it explicitly in your route through the `errorHandlerRef` attribute of the `route` element.

Comment: https://github.com/Dugayoyo/camel/blob/master/context    - full context. And log when i run this - https://github.com/Dugayoyo/camel/blob/master/log

Comment: If you are using XA transactions, then you should disable local JMS transactions in the Camel endpoint (i.e. transacted=false), since it will be the XA Connection Factory itself which starts the XA transaction. Also, you are missing the XA Resource Manager from your configuration: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/EIP_Transaction_Guide/files/XaJms-Sample.html.